# Remove trailing zeros in float representation

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, representation

Declaring a variable of this form `%.2f` what I want is to have maximum 2 digits after decimal point.

As it is now, it shows only two as expected, I would like to have also the trailing zeros removed.

```
formatString = "< %.2f Km"
```

where I use `formatString` as 
`String.format(formatString , value)`

Is there a way to do it during this part of the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804787/is-there-a-better-way-to-convert-a-double-to-its-exact-decimal-string/48804879#48804879

Comment: [Remove trailing zero in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/14984664)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your case:

```
double value = 3.502;
String formatString = "< %s Km";
String formattedString = String.format(formatString, new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(value));
```

Duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Comment: I've tested it, it keeps integer without `.`, it removes trailing `0` after the 1st decimal. I think it is the perfect solution for the question.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be much cleaner as simply `new DecimalFormat("< #.## Km").format(value)`, without using String.format at all?

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but in my case it still shows one 0 after whole numbers. e.g.: `100` is shown `100.0`. I would like to show whole numbers if they are like that. here is a snippet with my code: https://pastebin.com/RuxZPdDv , first is where is declared and the second one where it is returned

Comment: @LeoMessi If you use `new DecimalFormat("#.##")` instead of `new DecimalFormat(".##")`, it should also work for whole numbers